# Date format in body of email

Tags: google-apps-script, date-format, email

I'm using a very basic automated email script. The message that I want to send out out is simply a date. In the spreadsheet this is formatted as "06/11/2013" but when the email is received it appears in the body of the email as "Wed Nov 06 2013 00:00:00 GMT-0000 (GMT)".

I want it to appear formatted in the body of the email as just the date as it is down in the spreadsheet. Is there any way to do this? Here is the (very basic) script I am using:

```
function sendEmails() {
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
  var startRow = 2;  // First row of data to process
  var numRows = 2;   // Number of rows to process

  var dataRange = sheet.getRange(startRow, 1, numRows, 2)
  // Fetch values for each row in the Range.
  var data = dataRange.getValues();
  for (i in data) {
    var row = data[i];
    var emailAddress = row[0];  // First column
    var message = row[1];       // Second column
    var subject = "Date";
    MailApp.sendEmail(emailAddress, subject, message);
  }
}
```

Not a very advanced user but any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The data is stored in the spreadsheet as a `Date` and therefore will appear in the end content as `Date`. Use the `Utilities.formatDate` to convert this to a String

```
function sendEmails() {
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
  var startRow = 2;  // First row of data to process
  var numRows = 2;   // Number of rows to process

  var dataRange = sheet.getRange(startRow, 1, numRows, 2)
  // Fetch values for each row in the Range.
  var data = dataRange.getValues();
  for (i in data) {
    var row = data[i];
    var emailAddress = row[0];  // First column
    var message = Utilities.formatDate(row[1], "GMT" , "dd/MM/yyyy" );       // Second column
    var subject = "Date";
    MailApp.sendEmail(emailAddress, subject, message);
  }
}
```

Comment: Srik has the right method.  Another (dirtier) way of accomplishing this task is to simply format the column in your spreadsheet that contains the date as "Plaintext", and it will be formatted as just the date when the email is sent.